# Amazon EMR - Step failed with exitCode 127

Tags: rstudio, exit-code, amazon-emr

I am currently trying to configure an Amazon EMR instance with rstudio using the Amazon CLI and have followed the following tutorial: http://www.thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/launching-an-aws-emr-cluster-with-rstudio-hive-pig-and-hue/

Unfortunately I am encountering some errors involving the step to configure r studio: 
I have checked the logfile and this is the error line:

```
2016-04-03T13:21:25.590Z INFO waitProcessCompletion ended with exit code 127 : hadoop jar /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-WMW1HH4N...
2016-04-03T13:21:31.711Z INFO Step created jobs: 
2016-04-03T13:21:31.711Z WARN Step failed with exitCode 127 and took 16 seconds
```

Does anyone know what this exit code means? I have tried googling with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you put yarn logs? the error message you have put is so general

Comment: I've been led to believe exitCode 127 means either the command you're trying doesn't exist, or it doesn't have the appropriate execution permissions. I have not found a solution to this yet, so good luck!